# Скопировать в буфер обмена js

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть переменная login и password. Как мне по нажатию на кнопку (onlick), скопировать это:
Ваш логин: {login}
Ваш пароль: {password}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370896/how-to-copy-the-value-of-variable-in-javascript пожалуйста пользуйтесь гуглом))

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я просто гуглил на русском и везде копирование с input или другого тега. У меня была идея создать элемент с нужным текстом, скопировать текст, удалить. Оказалось так и нужно

Answer (score 2):

А так даже во фрейме работает и без разрешений:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  var inp = document.createElement('input')
  inp.value = "Hi! I'm copied by button"
  document.body.appendChild(inp)
  inp.select()
  
  if (document.execCommand('copy')) {
    console.log("Done!")
  } else {
    console.log("Failed...")
  }
  
  document.body.removeChild(inp)
})
```

```html
<button>Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может работать вот такое:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText("Hi! I'm copied by button")
    .then(() => console.log("Done!"))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
})
```

```html
<button>Copy</button>
```

Comment: document.execCommand устарел, поэтому да, лучше использовать navigator.clipboard.writeText

Comment: @GrimCap, спорно. Тот вариант работает вроде всегда, а этот запрашивает разрешение на работу с буфером. На мой взгляд тот лучше.

Comment: т.к. MDN не одобряет (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand), то, думаю, не о чем спорить

Comment: @GrimCap, поддержка браузерами не очень соответствует предупреждению. Точнее, очень не соответствует для команды `copy`.

Comment: Прекрасная поддержка, вполне соответствует: https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.clipboard

Comment: @GrimCap, я говорил про поддержку `document.execCommand('copy')`.

Answer (score -1):

Было бы неплохо если бы вы сами нашли ответ - первая ссылка в гугле
https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.php

```js
/* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
```

Comment: Я искал и посещал много сайтов, но я же написал, что мне нужно не с html тега скопировать текст, а заданный текст копировать при нажатии на кнопку