# Как скопировать значение input при клике на кнопку/иконку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите как скопировать содержимое input при клике на иконку?

```
<div class="form-group form-group__ico">
     <label for="card-num">Номер банковской карты получателя</label>
     <input name="card_num" type="text" class="form-control" id="card-num" required placeholder="2200280421677347">
     <img src="img/form-ico.svg" alt="Icon">
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я надеюсь, что вы не выложили реальный номер карты, ведь так?

Comment: Вам нужно само содержимое или значение placeholder, если значение не задано?

Comment: Это нереальный номер карты ) Скопировать нужно, когда уже ввели номер карты.

Comment: Посмотрите [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1145247/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-js)

Comment: https://w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1249936/182750